# java generics bounds

Tags: java, generics

I have the following code:

```
public <T extends SomeObject> long doSomething(T someObject){
    List<? extends SomeObject> l = new LinkedList<>();
    l.add(someObject);
}
```

this causes a compilation error - telling me that there is no suitable methods found: add(T),
why is that?

If `l` accept things that extends `SomeObject` shouldn't it accept `someObject` as it  bounds to extend `SomeObject`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
List<? extends SomeObject> l
```

What do you mean by that? Of course it will generate an error.

Take this example :`SomeObject` is `Fruit`, you have 2 derived classes `Apple` and `Orange`

Your list what will it contain? `Apple`s or `Orange`s? The compiler cannot tell. So it generates error.

If you replace  `List<? extends SomeObject> l` with `List<SomeObject> l`. Then this will work because `Apple` and `Orange` are both `Fruit`.

Comment: @bennyl No problem. I too tend to have this missuse of generics :)

Comment: Java generics are generally a fail. They have caused a record number of headeches around the globe and all they can accomplish is remove the need for an explicit downcast (meanwhile they add a whole lot of boilerplate code of their own). If your code isn't 100% warning-free, the whole shebang really amounts to allowing implicit downcasts. As Steve Yegge said, they could just allow the implicit downcast in a single paragraph of the JLS and have the same effect---without the headaches.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik take for example the sorting function. Wouldn't be easy to write one generic sorting function which would take any kind of objects primitives or non-primitives instead of writing one for each type? This is one of the advantages of Generics. Surely as everything else, they can be misleading if not used correctly

Comment: @AdelBoutros That's kind of a bad example---there really IS no way to write one piece of code that will sort both primitive and boxed arrays. On the other hand, where do you see the utility of generics in sorting, anyway? All it needs is `Comparable` objects, no generics involved.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Java Generics have an extremely elegant theoretical basis and make for really smooth code when used correctly. Just because you don't understand it or use it correctly doesn't mean there's something wrong with it. Of course when you fight with it and force it to do something incorrectly it's going to look ugly and not work. That is true with any advanced topic (e.g. Haskell, or advanced math). If you want something "easy" just use a dynamically-typed language; then you don't have to worry about any of this.

Comment: @user102008 Excellent argument! So you're telling the world of Java developers to better get a PhD in type theory or leave? Have you ever heard of [Steve Yegge](https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/next-big-thing)? This comment area is quite constrained, read what he has to say. As for "etremely elegant", maybe I'm missing something, please show me how to specify declaration-site type variance?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Aren't Lists, Sets and Maps generics in Java? Are you saying that ArrayList, HashedMap, etc are bad just because they implement Generics?

Comment: No, I'm saying something quite unrelated: that the whole generics  implementation in Java is a failure, much like checked exceptions. There's nothing specifically bad with the types you mention.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik List and Maps are generics implementation. Make up your mind! If generics are failure, then Lists and Maps are failure. Isn't this what you are saying ?

Comment: You just fail to understand my words. Java Generics is an implementation of type paremetrization for Java. That implementation is a failure. Lists and Maps use that feature, they don't **implement** it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik They don't implement it? And what is this [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java)?

Comment: Sigh... You are showing the code that implements `ArrayList<E>`. Can't you realize there's a difference between **using** a language feature and **implementing** that feature? `ArrayList<E>` **is not a language feature**---it's a Java class.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik And in the question asked here, isn't the user also **using** it? I don't see why you commented `Java generics are generally a fail`, that's all

Comment: I just felt like it. Consider it a spur-of-the-moment rant. There must be 20 questions every day here on SO from users having problems with Generics and every time I look at the question, my soul feels heavy considering how much time and energy I'd need to invest to go through his code and help him.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use this statement:

```
List<T> l = new LinkedList<T>();
```

This is no less type-safe then

```
List<SomeObject> l = new LinkedList<SomeObject>();
```

and additionally gives you an opportunity to get objects of type T from the list without casting. T is already SomeObject so no casting required to call methods of SomeObject on T.
And all that with less typing!

Back to the problem.

First thing to note is that wildcard type "?" means *unknown*, this is important.
You may, however, specify an upper (? extends) or a lower (? super) constraint to it.
You declared a list as "List".

List is known to have objects of SomeObject inside. but! the exact type of objects is unknown.

Compiler can not say if there are instances of "class A extends SomeObject" or instances of "class B extends SomeObject" inside the list.
If you call list.get() it can only say that there will be an object of type SomeObject.

```
SomeObject obj = list.get(1);   // Ok
```

But inserting an object of any(!) type is unsafe because the actual type of elements in the list is unknown.

You could wonder why wildcard type ever exists.
It is here to lower restriction in type casting that will be too strict otherwise.

Sample

```
class A { }

class A2 extends A { }

class B <T> {
    void change(T a) { .. };
    T read() { ..  };
}
```

If there were no wildcards we would not be able to do this: `B<A> b = new B<A2>();` - it does not work.
This is because type conversion from `B<A> to B<A2>` is unsafe.

Why? Let's look (copied from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ints.add(2);
List<Number> nums = ints;  // valid if List<Integer> were a subtype of List<Number>
nums.add(3.14);  
Integer x = ints.get(1);   // now 3.14 is assigned to an Integer variable!
```

What is the solution? Sometimes, we want to do such assignments or pass parameters in a general way!

Wildcard type helps here: `B<? extends A> b = new B<A2>();`
Method `B.void change(T a)` is now disabled - this is what your question was about and explained in the first part.

Method `B.T read()` is still valid and returns A: `A a = b.read();`. Yes, it returns A2 actually but to the caller of `b.read()` it's visible as A.

Wildcard types are widely used in Collections Framework.

Comment: `List<T> l = new LinkedList<T>();` T cannot be resolved to a type